# AWS Deep Learning AMI volume size exceeds free usage tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deep-learning, amazon-ami

I was creating a [Deep Learning AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01M0AXXQB) Amazon EC2 instance.

I have a free tier account. Under this I am eligible up to 30 GiB space. However, the new Deep Learning ubuntu AMI launched by Amazon has snapshot size of 50 GiB.

So, if I select this AMI, I will be charged. Is there any way or I have to choose Ubuntu Linux instance and manually install Libraries such as keras,tensorflow etc?

Comment: Were you able to install the libraries into other Ubuntu Linux instances to work with Deep Learning?

Comment: @Joe ,Yes I was.I took Ubuntu Instance and manually installed needed libraries such as Keras and Tensorflow.

Comment: Were you able to install all the libraries and still keep it under 30Gb to retain the free tier?

Comment: Yes.I only installed the needed libraries such as tensorflow , keras and their related dependencies.I think it all depends upon libraries you want to install.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that disk volume requires 50 GB of storage. In US regions, storage is 10c/GB/month so it would cost **$5/month**. You can reduce costs by deleting the EC2 instance (and the EBS volume) when it is not required (but you will lose any information you saved on it).

Actually, the free tier would cover the first 30GB, so you'd probably pay only **$2/month** for the excess.

Also, please note that you do **not** have a "free tier account". The account is a normal AWS account. However, new AWS accounts qualify for [free tiers of usage](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) within their first 12 months. If you exceed the free amounts, then you will be charged normal prices for the extra services consumed.